# How to render two different views, based on one and the same dataset simultaneously, in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, solid-principles

We use Laravel 5.2 framework in a LAMP environment with nginx as a balancing front and memcached as HTML cache storage.

We have almost standard caching procedure when cache miss invokes controller action, than middleware puts rendered result in a cache storage and returns response.

Until now we've used responsive markup and one and the same view for mobile and desktop pages.

Now due to some reasons we have to return mobile or desktop HTML page version depending on request headers but both of them still hosted at one and the same URL and use one and the same dataset.

Very simple and fast decision was to separate memcached instances and render two views simultaneously in the same controller action, returning views array, than iterate through array in a caching middleware to store mobile or desktop versions in a relevante memcached instance.

It looks something like this:

Controller action returns views array:

```
...
return [
    ViewType::MOBILE => view('mobile.newsPage', $params),
    ViewType::DESKTOP => view('news.newsPage', $params)
];
```

Middleware caching method distributes result to cache storage instances:

```
...
foreach ($response->original as $viewType => $view) {
    ...
    $html = $view->render();
    $viewTypesStores[$viewType]->put($key, $html, $cachingTime);
    ...
}
```

There are some doubts if we do violate Laravel MVC pattern or another Laravel idiom or SOLID principles, changing Controller Action type from view to array, returning different page types at one and the same URL and if there are some better way to render several views based on one dataset avoiding DB double querying.

Comment: [Laravel is neither an MVC framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-laravel-mvc-framework-you-should-forget-kali-dass/), nor is it particularly SOLID. So if that what you do there works, it works. If you want to know whether that approach is following Laravel idioms, you might wanna rephrase the question.

Comment: It's a hit on my picture of the world speaking about that Laravel does not present MVC. I've read the article but can't figure out why Models and View and Controlles are called this way if they are not. And how to distribute code by its role over an application now. Do you think also it's ok to return Array in a Controller public method if Laravel documentation says it should be View object or Void?

Comment: If Laravel docs say it should be a View or void, then it should not be an array. Otherwise you are breaking the contract and risk an error. Consider writing a custom Multiview object if Laravel doent have that.

Comment: Yep, this is cause for concern, as for me it looks like any of framework's minor update could break this implementation.

Comment: Anyway I've edited question body a little bid following your advice about violating some Laravel idioms except MVC pattern. Thanks!